# How to work with Fullcalendar in MVC5 in my file

Tags: javascript, view, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

my View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

```
@Scripts.Render("~Scripts/jquery.min.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~Scripts/moment.min.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~Scripts/fullcalendar.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~Scripts/Events.js")`
```

Events JavaScript:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month'    }   });
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month'    }   });
```

calendar id does not call the js file.

*How to enable the javascript file full calendar does not working in mvc5?*

Comment: You need to set an event source. Either as a [JSON Feed](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/), an [Array](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/), or as a [function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/).

Comment: use eventSource to specify the url, and do not reinitialize the calendar, also check in browsers console for error.

Answer (score 1):

I will Advise that you follow these following step:-

To get started:

Create a new `C#` MVC project and clear out the default view templates.

Download FullCalendar from here.

Download Twitter Bootstrap (I am using the stable version 2.3.2 until v3 is out of RC).

For both libraries, unpack and place the `CSS` file in your `/Content` folder, and the `JS` scripts in the `/Scripts` folder.

In your MVC project, add the bootstrap files to your script bundles. This is in `BundleConfig.cs` and is located in your `App_Start` folder.

You will also note I have added the `JQuery-UI JS` file to my `bundle` - this is needed to support drag/drop.

We will do our work in the default `index.cshml` page, so in there, place a DIV to hold the plugin:

```
<div id='calendar' style="width:65%"></div>
```

(note that the inline style is simply to force the width for screenshots inside the CodeProject publishing size guidelines!)

Finally, to prove its at least loading and rendering correctly we will add some basic `JS`, when the document is ready and loaded:

The initialization settings tell the plugin what to show in the header, the default view (in this case "agenda day" ..familiar to most), and to have a default time slot of 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for me was that I used 'use a layout page' for generating my view.
That layout page also has jquery bundles which interfered with the one on my view. 
So it was not loading all the libraries properly on my view.

So I made another view without referencing the layout page. and it worked.